# Model always giving prediction even if I gave it false data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I created an TensorFlow model which I trained it on 13 class of clothes, It works for the most part but if I gave the model an Image for a human face or something other that what it is trained for it will always give prediction, This is bad because for example when i use it in an android app and the photo has something wrong or just a totally unrelated image to the model it will still give prediction ... how can I fix that ?

My Model:

```
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(
                     include_top=False,
                     weights='imagenet',
                     input_shape=(image_width,image_height,3)
                     )
base_model.trainable=False
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        base_model,  
        tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(categorys_size, activation='softmax')])
```

How i predict on Android using TensorFlow-Lite:

```
val outputs = aiModel.process(input)
    val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
    val confidences = outputFeature0.floatArray
    var maxPos = 0
    var maxConfidence = 0f
    for (i in confidences.indices) {
        Log.d("Debug","Ai $i: ${confidences[i]}")
        if (confidences[i] > maxConfidence) {
            maxConfidence = confidences[i]
            maxPos = i
        }
    }
```

As suggested in the answer changed my output layer activation function to a sigmoid function, And this is the test result
Last layer in the model:

```
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(categorys_size, activation='sigmoid')])
```

Trained item prediction:

```
 0: 0.008963287
 1: 0.31714076
 2: 0.3260302
 3: 0.16326761
 4: 0.98595774
 5: 0.99898005
 6: 0.73391
 7: 0.105021596
 8: 0.6949855
 9: 0.23735091
 10: 0.10482347
 11: 0.44860303
 12: 0.972826
 13: 0.048107207

Prediction: 5
```

Non-trained 'False Data':

```
 0: 0.021587461
 1: 0.04939705
 2: 0.9529922
 3: 0.97660494
 4: 0.19534937
 5: 0.0668163
 6: 0.032978743
 7: 0.5045526
 8: 0.6911509
 9: 0.98788655
 10: 0.9927062
 11: 0.11638865
 12: 0.62173533
 13: 0.23424217

Prediction: 10
```

the model prediction is always >50% no matter what

Comment: This is how neural networks work, you cannot fix it as it is not a programming problem.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy okay it's my mistake but can't the model give me a percentage for the prediction ? like object detection ... The above code returns list as [0.1,0.01,.....0.9] but there's no percentage for how much this prediction is accurate

Comment: you could include a non-cloth class in the training and see if that helps.

Comment: @Kilian i thought about that but what if the user gave it an random thing, I can train the model on faces for example but what if the user sent an random item not a human face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your output layer activation function to a sigmoid function. This will output values between 0 and 1 for every class. Then you have actual probabilities per class. For the softmax function, all your probabilities will always add up to 1, so you will never have all the values close to 0.
In your postprocessing of your prediction, you iterate over the different outputs and then show the most probable prediction to the user. But if all probabilities in your output vector are below a certain threshold, you can just not put out a prediction at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try it and will write a comment if I need any more explanation

Comment: Please check the update in the question

Comment: When you do predictions on images you get a prediction of the class as well as the probability. Set a threshold level say .8 so if the prediction probability is less than that just declare the image an invalid input.

Comment: Then you need to revisit your training data once more, since your network did not learn the clear representation of what you want it to learn. Try to expand your training data and look into data augmentation.

Comment: Thanks for @Noltibus an Geryy P, I will clean/increase my dataset and increase my threshold